# Implementing Neumorphism UI in React Native Expo Managed Flow

Tags: react-native, user-interface, mobile, expo

I am trying to implement Neumorphism components by referring this [Website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-neu-element/v/1.1.9)
I had installed all the dependencies. But it is not working. Can anyone let me know whether this library could work at Expo Managed Flow?

The error is saying **NeuView is declared But it value is never read.**